# npm ERR! git dep preparation failed, cannot install packages

Tags: python, node.js, git, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install package.json file using the command `npm install`, but I'm getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\mussa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\mussa\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated eth-sig-util@1.4.2: Deprecated in favor of '@metamask/eth-sig-util'
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@2.2.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.2: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated bignumber.js@6.0.0: Custom ALPHABET bug fixed in v7.0.2
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@1.3.7: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-vm@2.6.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/vm. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@1.7.1: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated axios@0.17.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-common@1.3.1: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/common. Please update.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for ethereumjs-abi@git+ssh://git@github.com/ProjectWyvern/ethereumjs-abi.git (sha512-01FWolui9eTZdL/Zd8mNq+29unfRX4YsDltQ7fLZbavxF8j55w4U0tA/KzLv3UHUmC7tbT53q5Z9PPkr1uVqHw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for ethereumjs-abi@git+ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git (sha512-iJJBtbwT6cobjdVO192T6UpCscUBDFHsQS8JrxIOKIvkZsYaw93ZQJMgLOi2pbvr3AzdXc8AtHbvCrF6njpcSA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for ethereumjs-abi@git+ssh://git@github.com/ProjectWyvern/ethereumjs-abi.git (sha512-01FWolui9eTZdL/Zd8mNq+29unfRX4YsDltQ7fLZbavxF8j55w4U0tA/KzLv3UHUmC7tbT53q5Z9PPkr1uVqHw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for ethereumjs-abi@git+ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git (sha512-iJJBtbwT6cobjdVO192T6UpCscUBDFHsQS8JrxIOKIvkZsYaw93ZQJMgLOi2pbvr3AzdXc8AtHbvCrF6njpcSA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for bignumber.js@git+ssh://git@github.com/frozeman/bignumber.js-nolookahead.git (sha512-f2D7IzwfZEiFABIhgrwJTlWRsKd1HELI8MIeu0ETdxwaHNEoJnXStjHHK0yrlBlSe4AobmSkeDWXd9+7Uw4v7g==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for bignumber.js@git+ssh://git@github.com/frozeman/bignumber.js-nolookahead.git (sha512-f2D7IzwfZEiFABIhgrwJTlWRsKd1HELI8MIeu0ETdxwaHNEoJnXStjHHK0yrlBlSe4AobmSkeDWXd9+7Uw4v7g==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.9: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! npm ERR! sha512-iJJBtbwT6cobjdVO192T6UpCscUBDFHsQS8JrxIOKIvkZsYaw93ZQJMgLOi2pbvr3AzdXc8AtHbvCrF6njpcSA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-iJJBtbwT6cobjdVO192T6UpCscUBDFHsQS8JrxIOKIvkZsYaw93ZQJMgLOi2pbvr3AzdXc8AtHbvCrF6njpcSA== but got sha512-Jaq/apiE79exkvaowWgVShb1x6hci6DObPWofgRy7hkA2GCAtOe6zhq9joVKy+QDgsxalPg2NZMgSyl0utPlBg==. (14116 bytes)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\mussa\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-09T16_23_01_389Z-debug.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mussa\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-09T16_23_03_344Z-debug.log
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "opensea-js": "^1.2.7"
  }
}
```

I have:

- nodejs v16.14.0
- npm 7.6.0
- Python 3.10.2
- Visual Studio Community 2022 with c++ workload
- Visual Studio Build Tools 2017

If someone can help me it would be awesome!

Comment: You're getting that git error at the start because of those `git+ssh://git@github.com/ProjectWyvern/ethereumjs-abi.git (...) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.` errors at the end. If something's pulling raw git repositories, stay away from it, because that's the easiest way to distribute compromised code. Find a better wallet library that actually uses npm properly instead of circumventing it once the main code is in place.

Comment: you mean ```@truffle/hdwallet-provider```

Comment: Probably. Whichever of those three dependencies in your own package.json uses `ethereumjs-abi` etc.

Comment: I solved the problem by downgrading my node to 14.18.1

Comment: given that the error wasn't node related, the version downgrade is not what solved it, even if the _process_ of reinstalling node did.